# fetch sql data using php and show in a html table using different names?

Tags: php, html, sql, html-table, data-retrieval

I sava data in sql table as

- male as 1
- female as 2

now I want to get that data back to HTML page and print, but data print as 1/2.how I print that data as Male and Female???

Comment: use an `if else`, `if gender == 1 print male, else print female`

Comment: You should use php as a programming language and use if statement in your code.
if($data=='1') echo 'Male'; else echo 'Female';

Comment: Sounds fine - what's your question about this? Is this question in any way related to HTML, or SQL?

Comment: my sql tabe gender row i save male=1, female=2, other=3 ,now I want to retrieve data and print on HTML table, but in gender column data print as 1,2,3 . i want to print that data as male, female ,other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL, you can do it inside SQL statement just like the example below.

```
SELECT IF(n_gender = 1, 'male', 'female') AS s_gender 
FROM   students;
```

Comment: how to add 3 types like male, female, other

Comment: you can use `CASE` statement

Comment: if it does not affect much of your code, you can restructure your table and make use of ENUM('male', 'female', 'other') and have a default value of 'male'. this is just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

add php(after myself query):

```
if(column_id == 1){
     echo 'male';

}
else if(column_id == 2){
     echo 'female';
}
```

As simple as that, you just need to put if else if statement in php.

Answer (score 0):

Use the query and obtain the value for gender as 1 or 2.

(Better use 3 also as an option for 'other' gender)

After that, assign 1 for male and 2 for female in PHP using the following part.

```
if(column_id == 1){
     $gender = 'Male';

}
else if(column_id == 2){
     $gender = 'Female';
}
else{
     $gender = 'Other' ;
}
```

Now, in your HTML section you can use

```
<? echo $gender ?>
```

to show the gender. Whether in a table or other format, this will surely work.

```
<table>

  <tr>
    <th> Name </th>
    ...............
    <th> Gender </th>
  </tr>
<!-- Above code for Table Headings !-->

  <!-- Now for data --!>
 <tr>
   <td> Kiran </td>
   ................
   <td> <? echo $gender ?> </td>
 </tr>
```

As you probably are handling multiple data, then use an array instead of a single '$gender' variable.

You can run a loop inside HTML in same manner.

To know about arrays in php, visit here : https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php